# Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: parsing

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
        Text="Registration"</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
```

What is the problem in this? I am getting following error:

"Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed."

To my knowledge, this is a good code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a closing tag(>) after the `Text="Registration"`in the first LinkButton tag

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Registration"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: @Kirs Sudh If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you verymuch, its simple. need to be bit cautious.